# image not showing in activity file when declaring it

Tags: android

I am creating a app using image switcher.I have copied some images to `res/drawable-mdpi` folder
when trying to declare it its not showing in drawable.

```
Integer pics[]={R.drawable.}
```

and even image switcher not showing

```
final ImageSwitcher iswitcher=(ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.);
```

Comment: what mean of copy here?

Comment: Have you tried Project/clean (assuming you're working in Eclipse)?

Comment: copying images to the res/drawable folder

Comment: You might have forget to set layout using `setContentView()`?

Comment: remove `import android.R;` from import section.

Comment: thanks i have tried cleaning the project still i cant able to get that

Comment: thanks for the reply but I didnt import android.R

Comment: I guess we need more code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1) Your image name may be started with First alphabet which is not allowed in Android.

2) Sometimes in Eclipse this types of problems occurs so try to rebuild your project. for that  Go to **Project**->**Clean**->**Run**.

Hope you will get this:

Answer (score 1):

First check your R file in `gen` folder.

It contains drawable field like this

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
```

check your image name in this.

If it is not containing then please check your All layout(xml) files.
whether is it ok or not. sometimes incorrect xml file will occure errors in R.java file .

If all layouts are ok then check your image name.
uppercase is not allowed for resource names.. only lowercase(a-z), 0-9, .(dot) and _ are valid.

Then `Clean` your project.

If all thing is perfect then Restart your eclipse then clean & build your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply there is no R file in gen folder..what shall i do?

Comment: Check your layout & all image names.